# Проблема с MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том, что когда перезагружаешь страницу, выборка из MYSQL остается, она не удаляется, а только с каждым разом увеличивается на один, как сделать, что-бы не увеличивалось

Вот код

```
       $result = mysql_query('SELECT `school` . `school`,  `street`
     FROM
      `datacenter`, `school` 
        WHERE
          `datacenter` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` 
         AND
       `datacenter` . `name` = "'.$name_teacher.'"');

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
        {
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно проверку поставить на повторную отправку данных.

Comment: ок, уже сделал